# Need a date field in Cognito Forms that displays just the Month & Year in the date-picker

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to format a Date field in Cognito Forms to just display 'Month & Year' and not the calendar day in the Date-picker?

I am asking the user to mention the Expected Project Completion Time in Month/Year format in my form.

The user needs to pick just the Month & Year, as the calendar day is irrelevant(not valid even) to my occasion.

Any solutions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same issue - I could not find a way to directly limit the date field so, I created 2 separate "choice" fields, titled one month, one year, and gave the options there.

Hope this helps.